# Fitting to already fitted data

Tags: regression

Some experimental data was fitted, by using last squares, to a function $f_1(t;c_1)$, that depends parametrically on $c_1$ (that is, the best $c_1$ parameter, according to LS, was found by fitting).

I wish to fit the same data to another (but quite similar) function $f_2(t;c_2)$, but I do not have access to those data.

Intuitively I think that I can just sample $f_1(t;c_1)$ and fit $f_2(t;c_2)$ to those points.

My doubts are:

- How confident can I be about $c_2$?
- Is there a simple and better way?
- What can I know about the $c_2$ obtained?
- Is there some bias that can be estimated?

Any help is appreciated, even if it does not address all the points above

Comment: Do you know anything about the quality of the originally fitted model? E.g. if relevant model assumptions are fulfilled and how small the residual standard deviation is?

Comment: @Michael M, I know that the model fits very well the experimental data. Better that $f_2$. Also that the residues 'should' be relatively small, around 0.1-1% of the predicted values

Comment: @MichaelM Just to notify you properly

Comment: Is $t$ controlled by the experimenter or passively observed? If observed, do you know anything about its distribution? Do you have any more information about the residuals of $f_1$ (e.g. what type of distribution, are they independent, does their magnitude vary with $t$ or the predicted output, anything else you can say in terms of numbers)?

Comment: @user20160 $t$ is controlled by the experimenter, it can be assumed that the error in $t$ is negligible. I have no info. about the $f_1$ residuals, I think that their MAD should slightly increase with $t$.
As I have no access to the raw data, I cannot be 100% sure. But it is almost sure that residues are very small (in absolute value) compared to the corresponding $f_1$ estimations. I bet that to suppose a  normal distribution is reasonable

Comment: What do you mean by 'fitting the same data' and 'I do not have access to those data'? To me these seem in conflict according to the way I interpret it *(If you can fit $y_i = f_1(t_i;c_1)$ then you have all you need to know to fit $y_i = f_2(t_i;c_2)$)*.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I think the OP means that $y_i=f_1(t_i;c:_1)$ had been already fitted by someone else, to data the OP has not access to. So s/he is asking how to fit $y_i=f_2(t_i;c:_2)$ to data s/he doesn't have. For this reason, s/he would like to _simulate_ data from the fitted model. A parametric bootstrap of sorts...

Comment: In that case it wont work. Or at least, the interpretation should be limited. The proposed simulation of data is not a simulation of the data but instead a simulation of the function that has been fitted to the data (information from residuals is lost). With such a procedure one may answer whether f_2 is similar to f_1, and only indirectly (if f_1 is very similar to the data 0.1% - 1%) one may argue that the function f_2 is similar to the data as well. In this case.. I guess it is better not to speak about fitting f_2 to f_1 or data, but instead finding c_2 such that f_2 best approximates f_1.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings "...one may argue that the function f_2 is similar to the data as well".  Right, that is why I thought in that procedure, but I just can argue intuitively, and that is my problem.
"I guess it is better not to speak about fitting f_2 to f_1 or data, but instead finding c_2 such that f_2 best approximates f_1" I completely agree, but that may sound shocking. I believe that people prefer that I make a statement about how well my $f_2$ represents the data. That is a more direct statement. No one cares about f_1.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I agree. In this context it makes much more sense to talk of function approximation than of regression. However, if the OP has at least access to the SE $\sigma$ of estimation for $c_1$, s/he could simulate from the distribution of $c_1$, assumed to be $N(\hat{c}_1, \sigma^2)$, simulate $t_i$ from an uniform distribution over $[t_{min}, t_{max}]$, and generate a data set $S=\left[\left(t_i,\ y_i=f_1(t_i,c_1^{(i)}\right)\right]_{i=1}^N$. Not ideal, but better than considering $c_1$ known.

Comment: And, if the OP has also access to the SE of the residuals, s/he could add random noise to the above data set in the same way. On the other hand, if none of the statistics describing the fit of $f_1$ to data are available, there's nothing to simulate.

Comment: @user1420303 people may prefer all they want, but it's a fact that you cannot say anything about how well $f_2$ fits data you don't have. Even the simulation approach I described (which assumes you have estimates for the SE of $c_1$ and the SE of residuals) makes numerous assumptions and cannot be considered a valid substitute for having the actual data.

Comment: @DeltaIV, It would be useful give some statistics even if it is not as good as having the raw data. My interest is to compare simulated data with experimental results. Simulated values have errors much bigger that the experimental ones (maybe 2 orders of magnitude). For making a comparison I need a model which provides a numerical parameter (I need c_2), and have c_1 obtained by others by fitting. f_1 and f_2 are very similar functions used for fitting to that class of experiments. They are used almost interchangeably.

Comment: @user1420303 to follow the procedure I suggested (which, I repeat, it's an hack, and most likely not valid), you need the fit statistics for $f_1$. Can you get them from the authors who fitted it? Even if they're not keen on sharing data, they might be ok with sharing fit stats, or they may have included them in some reports. The fact that $f_2$ and $f_1$ are so similar doesn't change the fact that $f_1$  **was** fitted to real data, and $f_2$ **won't**. On the contrary, if they're so similar, why don't you just use $f_1$? What kind of information do you expect to gain by fitting a similar...

Comment: ...function to fake data? Also, you're talking now about computations and experiments. What data was $f_1$ fitted to? Experiments? Simulations?
The question is unclear, and you should edit it. Also, it would really help if you could: 1. tell us which class of experiments you're talking about; 2. show the functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ you're talking about; 3. show some plot of the fit of $f_1$ to data. Even if you don't have the actual numeric data, maybe you have some plot without scales? That's quite common in publications coming from industry. Right now, we're talking about an highly...

Comment: ...dubious statistical procedure ("fitting" a function to another function which was fit to unavailable data, without even access to the statistics of the original fit), and we don't even have a clear description of the real problem. Under these constraints, it's hard to give an answer other than "don't do this" .